# Simplify test where one of pregiven list element values is not missing and is TRUE

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I would like to ask this, because it is hard to search for. Is there more efficient way to write the following:

```
a <- list(x=FALSE,z=TRUE,l=list()) # a$y is not defined, list contains also lists
f <- function() 1

if(!is.null(a$x)) { if(a$x==TRUE) f() } 
if(!is.null(a$y)) { if(a$y==TRUE) f() } 
if(!is.null(a$z)) { if(a$z==TRUE) f() } 
[1] 1
```

The idea is that if list any of pre-given list elements `x`, `y` or `z` have value `TRUE` function `f()` is called and otherwise not.

To aim is to run function `f()` only once, and write the function call `f()` only once to the code. Function `f()` is run if one of conditions `x`, `y` or `z` hold. The conditions are stored in the list `a`, which contains also other elements. However, list `a` might not contain all conditions, only some of them, which makes the missing conditions to be false.

**EDIT:**

I found quite convenient solution:

```
for (b in c("x","y","z")) { 
    if (!is.null(a[[b]]) & c(a[[b]]),F)[1] == T ) { 
         print(f())
         break 
    } 
}
```

but in order to prevent error:

```
if(!is.null(a[["y"]]) & a[["y"]] == T) 1
```

> Error in if (!is.null(a[["y"]]) & a[["y"]] == T) 1 : 
>        argument is of length zero

I had to make a coalesce-like solution `c(a[["y"]],F)[1]`:

```
if(!is.null(a[["y"]]) & c(a[["y"]],F)[1] == T) 1
```

which works, but does not look so nice, because I am not sure whether the following condition will work always, even if it does here (?):

```
> c(NULL,1) == c(1)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a list embedded inside another list, ie nested lists, we would rather use `rapply`

```
a <- list(x=FALSE,z=TRUE,l=list()) 
f <- function() 1
rapply(a,function(k)if(!is.null(k)&k==T)f())
z 
1 
b=list(x=FALSE,Z=TRUE,l=list(x=TRUE,y=TRUE))
rapply(b,function(k)if(!is.null(k)&k==T)f())
  Z l.x l.y 
  1   1   1
```

Comment: Recursive apply looks nice. However, the problem was also to test element "y" which is not in the list.

Comment: The condition is `!is.null(a$y)` which of course will return `FALSE` and hence there is no need of it since it will forever be `FALSE`. If there was an expression that we were to evaluate when the condition is `FALSE` then we would have taken that into consideration. But now when the codition is False, we do nothing., and we already know that the condition is False. Why check it?

Comment: Edited the question proposing solution, but not sure about whether found a decent solution.

Comment: What is your aim precisely?

Comment: To run function `f()` if one of conditions `x`, `y` or `z` hold. The conditions are stored in a list, which contains also other elements. However, the list might not contain all conditions, only some of them.

Comment: Then you just need to check the present conditions.. The absent condition cannot hold and thus `f` won't be run

Answer (score 0):

With this kind of data:

```
a <- list(x=FALSE,z=TRUE,l=list()) # a$y is not defined, list contains also lists
f <- function() 1
```

the aim was to run function `f()` if one of conditions `x`, `y` or `z` hold. Thanks to hint from @Onyambu, it is necessary to test only conditions which are found in the list, because not found conditions are false. Below are steps which were used in final solution (last execution row):

```
> intersect(names(a),c("x","y","z"))
[1] "x" "z"
> a[intersect(names(a),c("x","y","z"))]
$x
[1] FALSE

$z
[1] TRUE

> unlist(a[intersect(names(a),c("x","y","z"))])
    x     z 
FALSE  TRUE 
> any(unlist(a[intersect(names(a),c("x","y","z"))]))
[1] TRUE
> if (any(unlist(a[intersect(names(a),c("x","y","z"))]))) f()
[1] 1
```